# how can i check full DOM path easily

Tags: dom

im making some script with python PAMIE module.

inside my script  im using internet explorer object and to handle this object

im using DOM path but it not easy to check Full dom element path .

for example , how can i search full dom path such like format?

```
   divChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes[0].nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0]
```

it not easy to check manually

if anyone help me much apprecaite!

Answer (score 0):

could you identify the node by object id ?

```
document.getElementById("elementId")
```

Comment: I assume not otherwise you'd be doing it?

Comment: hello but this method is not what i want. i want to extract full dom path if possible automatcially. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to use this : https://github.com/asatour/jquery-domPath.
To get DOM Path of HTML jquery element

```
<body>
<div class="module" id="products-block">
    <div class="description">
        <h1 class="section-title">
            product general description
        </h1>
        <ul class="products">
            <li>Cameras</li>
            <li>TV</li>
            <li>Computers</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

JavaScript :

```
var products_domPath = $(".products").domPath();
```

Output:

```
["div#products-block.module > div.description > ul.products"]
```